# Calculation of previous day through yesterday.setDate(currentDay.getDate() - 1) fails

Tags: typescript, date

I'm trying to calculate the dates of the current and the previous 6 days. This [should work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5511323/calculate-the-date-yesterday-in-javascript) by simply subtracting 1 from the previous date, so I implemented my current solution like this:

```
        let currentDay = new Date();
        let nextDay = new Date();
        for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            nextDay.setDate(currentDay.getDate() - i);
            console.log("i=" + i + "->" + nextDay);
        }
```

However, this is the output:

```
i = 0 -> Thu Dec 03 2020 10: 20: 51 GMT + 0100(Central European Standard Time)  //today
i = 1 -> Wed Dec 02 2020 10: 20: 51 GMT + 0100(Central European Standard Time)  //yesterday
i = 2 -> Tue Dec 01 2020 10: 20: 51 GMT + 0100(Central European Standard Time)  //day before yesterday
i = 3 -> Mon Nov 30 2020 10: 20: 51 GMT + 0100(Central European Standard Time)  //3 days ago
i = 4 -> Fri Oct 30 2020 10: 20: 51 GMT + 0100(Central European Standard Time)  //skips an entire month
i = 5 -> Mon Sep 28 2020 10: 20: 51 GMT + 0200(Central European Summer Time)    //skips another month, 2 days and switches to summertime
i = 6 -> Fri Aug 28 2020 10: 20: 51 GMT + 0200(Central European Summer Time)    //skips another month
```

It worked as expected when running during the end of last month (where the current month was not escaped). It fails as it enters November. I can't seem to find the cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're never recreating `nextDate` from the initial day. Take a look at this:

```
function addDays(a_oDate: Date, days: number): Date {
  a_oDate.setDate(a_oDate.getDate() + days);
  return a_oDate;
  }

function printLast7Days(a_oDate: Date): void {
  for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    let nextDay = new Date(a_oDate); // recreate date from the initial date
    addDays(nextDay, -i); // effectively subtracts i days
    console.log("i=" + i + "->" + nextDay.toDateString());
    }
}

printLast7Days(new Date());
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwCaoCLIJ4GcAUyA+nFlAKYBciZ5ANIqjrtWCALYBG5ATgJTVaiAN4BYAFCIUJWgDpc5KLUIzkFWQHNFyvogDUjZnwDcEqT0UgeSYqTXlTkxAF8JE0JFgJEABx4wwKAAZZFwoAHYsPBU7CkF7AUQANzgYVBEzRGA4HkR8ABtFRBhEAF5EAAZjYsQAHkRw6pg9PV0xJylCqEQwcgAPJRwynvIAdxp7GNoTRAB6WcQLCAt7Qwosnjh2RCgAC3JisBhYZHy18kypNExmfF6BqIYAWhgZ+cRyYGByaBgk8ny2EQuBAnCgPGQ0FwNSYeEuiAgCFwcEKsnycA0+AARDBSlj9DUDFingA+fEGe6DbCyKCxcgAZXBAUxfBM8Nc4g5Ej8AWCoQiUQIvXGOhMQA)

Comment: Thanks, adding `nextDay = new Date(currentDay);` actually fixed it. I just still can't grasp where my error lies. My solution should: Calculate the constant `currentDay`; Initialize `nextDay` once; set `nextDay` to `currentDay - n * amount`. Shouldn't the result without re-initialization be the same?

Comment: @Beltway if `setDate()` recieves a negative number it will switch months, which is fine but - in your case `nextDate` is already in the past month after 4-5 iterations and it will continue to switch months because `nextDate` is never reset to the current date